# Construct a regular expression for a specified language

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$ I need to find a regular expression for this language:

- The language where the number of $a$'s and $b$'s is equal and for every prefix of a word the absolute value of the difference between the number of $a$'s and $b$'s isn't greater than 2

But I can't seem to find an expression for this language. From what I understand for each $w\in L_2$, $\#_a(w)= \#_b(w)$ and for every prefix $p$ such that $w=pu$, $|\#_a(p)- \#_b(p)| \leq 2$, so I need to somehow enforce that for every $a$ there will be a $b$ and that the difference between them will never exceed $2$, yet I don't think I know how. Can I make the expression include conditions? i.e if $|\#_a(p)- \#_b(p)| = 1$ can I only accept substrings such that $|\#_a(p)- \#_b(p)| \leq 2$ would be kept?

Comment: Please focus on one question only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the regular expression is easier to find using a DFA, but an explaination may be possible without (although the reasonning is the same).

First, note that a word of this language (let's note it $L$) is necessarily of even length. We will then consider pairs of consecutive letters in a word $w\in L$:

- if the word $w = uv$ with $u = ab$ or $u = ba$, then it is clear that $v\in L$;
- if $u = aa$, then necessarily the first letter of $v$ is a $b$. Consider $v = b\alpha v'$, with $\alpha\in \{a, b\}$:

  - if $\alpha = b$, then $v' \in L$ and we are back to square one;
  - else, $\alpha = a$, and we can apply the reasonning we did for $v$ to $v'$;
- it is the same thing for $u = bb$.

A corresponding regular expression could then be:

> $$(ab + ba + aa(ba)^*bb + bb(ab)^*aa)^*$$

Answer (score 0):

So I might've come up with the answer looking at [Brian M. Scott answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3857014)

if I build the regular expression
$$
(aabb + bbaa)^*
$$
The parity between $a$'s and $b$'s is always kept, easily proven using induction (using the same outline as in the cited answer above), and for every substring, $p$, $|\#_a(p) - \#_b(p)| \le 2$,
because for every substring, $x \in \{aabbaabb, aabbbbaa, bbaaaabb, bbaabbaa\}$, $|\#_a(x) - \#_b(x)| \le 2$

Comment: $ab$ is a word of the initial language, but not of your regular expression.

Comment: @Nathaniel yeah I saw it just after I posted the answer, though I think I might be in the right direction